# NaN при заполнении формы

Tags: javascript

Хотел скрыть подтверждение пароля и автоматически его заполнять из основного текстового поля.
Вот код:

```
<input type="text" size="30" name="password" id="password" value="" 
onkeyup="document.forms.registr.confirm_password.value=+this.value;" />
<input type="text" class="text" size="30" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value="" />
```

В итоге при вводе в поле password символов a..z возникает в confirm_password - NaN, а при вводе цифр, всё хорошо. Я читал в инете про NaN, только не пойму почему в моём случае он возникает, я ведь всего лишь копирую значение одного поля в другое.
Подскажите пожалуйста?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело в строке
`document.forms.registr.confirm_password.value=+this.value`
Для чисел +this.value равно this.value, а строки приводятся к числам - получается NaN. Поменяйте местами + и = или просто уберите + .

Comment: Спасибо что разъясниили

Answer (score 1):

**Уже ответили до меня :)**
*"document.forms.registr.confirm_password.value=+this.value;" <- плюс перед this.value так и задуман?*

Используйте jquery или хотя бы функции, не надо прямо ... в код.

Может лучше так:

```
 <script>
    function do_something(_this) { document.forms.registr.confirm_password.value=_this.value; }

    // или jquery
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
         $("#password").keyup(function()
          {
             $("#confirm_password").val($("#password").val());
          });
       });
 </script>

    <input type="text" size="30" name="password" id="password" value="" onkeyup="do_something(this);" />
    <input type="text" class="text" size="30" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value="" />
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример с jQuery

Comment: Ой, сразу не обратил внимание, зачем нижнее подчёркивание перед _this ???

Comment: Надо же как-то назвать переменную).

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. (немножко поправил jquery пример)